# Tengo este ERROR! no entiendo porque aparece... (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Este es mi codigo:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    user_phone VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    user_pass VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts( 
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_date DATE NOT NULL,
    post_province_origin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_province_goal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_locality_origin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_locality_goal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_descrip VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    user_id INT,
    post_user_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    post_user_phone VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
    msg_id INT NOT NULL,
    msg_price VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (msg_id, post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(post_id)
);
```

el error que tengo es en la tabla de messages...

**No puedo crear tabla `app_web_dl`.`messages` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

que puede estar mal? vi que muchos ponen el constraint.. pero en la universidad no me lo enseñaron .. no se como se usa el contraint...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver tu problema es que al referenciar la foreign key, no se corresponde con la tabla previa...

En tu tabla POSTS la llave PRIMARIA es compuesta (user_id, post_id) por lo que al relacionarla deberias hacerlo por esos dos campos, pero solo usas uno.

```
CREATE TABLE posts( 
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_date DATE NOT NULL,
    post_province_origin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_province_goal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_locality_origin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_locality_goal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_descrip VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    user_id INT,
    post_user_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    post_user_phone VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id),     # <---esta es tu llave compuesta
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
    msg_id INT NOT NULL,
    msg_price VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    post_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (msg_id, post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(post_id)     # <--- aqui deberia ser user_id, post_id
);
```

Considerando que ya estas relacionando las tablas creo que lo apropiado es que en tu tabla POSTS uses solo POST_ID como PRIMARY KEY, esto deberia resolver tu problema.

Comment: para mi el error es al reves.. sobra user_id en la tabla posts... si el id es unico por mensaje, el usuario es innecesario...

Comment: ah bien, lo voy a probar! igual estuve probando y me funciono cambiado de lugar las primary keys de la tabla posts dejandolo asi:
```
PRIMARY KEY(post_id, user_id)
```
ahora me anda jaja

Comment: y la tabla messages tiene el mismo problema.. la clave compuesta es innecesaria....

Comment: @gbianchi si lees el ultimo parrafo, eso precisamente es lo que digo, en el codigo solo muestro cual es el error, por favor lee completo antes de publicar una respuesta que pueda confundir al usuario que pregunta. adicionalmente la llave compuesta en messages, no provoca/produce el error ya que es la ultima tabla en la relacion.

Comment: Ah perdon... lo lei, pero no lo entendi asi.. pido disculpas.. igual, tu forma de decirlo tampoco fue muy agradable. Tal vez estaria bien que explicaras porque es innecesaria la clave compuesta...